# Card design interaction

Tags: user-behavior, user-expectation, users, experience, card-views

I do have a doubt wrt to the card interaction. We are designing this card for reports.

**The primary action for this card is to view this report, followed by downloading the report or following this report**

Thru data, we know that people first view the report and then take necessary action i.e download or follow.

There are 2 variants for this card
**Card 1** >> The card itself is clickable and on hover, we do have some micro interaction and view written on the thumbnail to make it obvious for the user

**Card 2** >> Entire card is clickable and All the CTAs are available upfront to the user

I'm in dilemma between cards 1 and 2. In terms of functionality and UX pov, card 2 works the best. Card 1 design is a solved problem as people are familiar with click behavior. Card 1 functionality is well-known to tech-savvy people in the younger age group but the same is not true for people in their 40s-50s or beyond.

[image]

Please help and thank you in advance.

Comment: I somewhat agree with the argument made on card 1. Not every user understands the card design well. It is a trial run that will happen when I click on it. Will it view/download?

Comment: "Card 1 functionality is well-known to tech-savvy people in the younger age group but the same is not true for people in their 40s-50s or beyond." Have you derived that from your observable user testing? Or do you have general studies to support this assertion?

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles No we haven't done any user testing

Comment: Please elaborate the difference between card 1 and 2. The only difference I see is card 2 has everything card 1 has except "View".  And the bulleted description confuses me.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles Primary action for this card is to view the report. So the question is should the view be shown upfront to the user or showing some micro-interaction on the card is sufficient to tell user that it is clickable and on clicking it will open the report.

Comment: I realize, I don't understand the problem you're trying to solve. Is it as simple as whether "View" clutters the interface? I don't think so. What am I missing?

Comment: The question here is whether it is evident enough for the user that the card will make the user view the report and will adding too many CTAs will add cognitive load on the user i.e time taken to make a decision.

Answer (score 2):

**I think Card 1 is better.** I find it easy to understand each of its [affordances](https://uxplanet.org/ux-design-glossary-how-to-use-affordances-in-user-interfaces-393c8e9686e4).

For my part, I will always try to see if a report interests me, and only if it does, will I download it. When I see **Card 1**, there is a very clear link and icon informing the user that this option allows you to **view** the content (which is what I would do, and which, in your own words, is the primary intended action).

On the other hand, **Card 2** does not have this **"View"** option. Perhaps some users may infer that by clicking on the image they can view the content. But I strongly doubt that an implicit behavior that requires a discoverability process *(and thus a high cognitive load)* works better than an explicit option.

Finally, and probably because I do not know what the app is about, I find it very confusing what **Follow** might mean in a downloadable item.

Comment: If you follow a report you will start receiving updates on the report whenever a new edition is available

Comment: Ahh, I see, now it makes sense. Even though it's not part of your question, I think there is a possible problem: People who have downloaded the report but don't follow up on it may not know that the report was changed at a later date. I don't know if you have a notification process, but maybe I'd add something like "date modified" or, if users are logged in, then track them and if there is a new version of the report, they might get a notification because they have shown interest in that report, which means it's more or less important to them.

Answer (score 0):

Card two works best from the POV you are describing.

It's not redundant, less visual noise and follows the progressive disclosure.

Two points that could be improved tho.

1. What is the actions hierarchy? It's not defined, they have the same weight.
2. Make sure there's a clear signifier that users know they can click and open the card. Most libraries use shadows for interactive components (Jackobs law)

https://m2.material.io/design/environment/light-shadows.html#research